# regeneratorRuntime is not defined at chunk-vendors in vue-cli modern build

Tags: babeljs, vue-cli-3

@vue/cli-service@3.2.0

```
vue-cli-service build --modern
```

The `dist/index.html` threw the error:

```
Error occur! ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at chunk-vendors.05e8cd04.js:1
```

`regeneratorRuntime` from `node_modules` was not exist in modern build, and `async/await` in **source code** will not be transformed either.

**package.json**

```
"browserslist": [
    ">= 0.5% in CN",
    "iOS >= 9",
    "not ie > 0",
    "not Edge > 0",
    "not Android < 5",
    "not dead"
]
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
  ],
}
```

Should I import the `regeneratorRuntime` at entry?

```
import '@babel/runtime/regenerator'
```

====== Update ========

The `chunk-vendors` was executed before `index`, so import the `regenerator` in `main.js` is useless.

```
<script type="module" src="/js/chunk-vendors.9c8f8aec.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/js/index.06514fac.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I introduced the `regenerator-runtime` script directly in html.

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.1/runtime.min.js" defer></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The `regeneratorRuntime` global variable will be defined before `chunk-vendors` execute.